# Saving multiple editText to file

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, and I'm using eclipse.

I have 2 screens. The main screen has a button (newScenario) and a `ExpandableListView`. My second view has a bunch of editText fields. (scenario_name , eng1, trans1, eng2 ,trans2……)

I need to be able to save the editText inputs to file where the scenario_name will be used as the .txt name and also be displayed in the `ExpandableListView`. Then if that file is chose it needs to be displayed on a new screen(if possible using a template)

Is this possible?

Comment: save the editText inputs to file ? for what purpose you want to store in a file.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy the purpose for storing it in a file is because i need it to be called later on (when the app is re-opened), and it is also a prerequisite for my application.

Comment: then store those values in SQLite database and use those values where ever you want

Comment: oh okay thanks. i thought that since its only text data that a .txt file would be best. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        Iterator<String> inputIterator = inputList.iterator();
        while(inputIterator.hasNext()){
            stringBuilder.append(inputIterator.next() + ";");
        }
        FileOutputStream fout = context.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME + ".txt", context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);

        osw.write(stringBuilder.toString());
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
```

I used this in the past to construct CSV files from editTexts. inputList is a String List with the info that I take from my editTexts.

P.S: Using MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated I did this long time ago. Now I dont know which option is better

Comment: If it was useful don't forget to vote it and mark as answer thank you!